# Chart with number of open complaints split by months

Tags: excel

I would like to generate a chart with the monthly status of opened claims based on the creation date and closing date.

Let's suppose I have 3 claims:

```
Claim No. | Date created | Date closed
X7348     | 01.Jan       | 01.April
Y6778     | 01.Mar       | 01.April
G7847     | 01.Feb       | 01.May
```

The chart should indicate the status like this:

```
Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun
1   | 2   | 3   | 3   | 1   | 0
```

So, claim `X7348` had the status open in Jan, also in Feb, Mar and April.

**Update:**

In fact my data's have and XML source and loaded into a `Table` which can change the range.
I think the result must come from a `Pivot`.
I've tried to create a calculated field with `COUNTIFS` formula behind, but give some errors like the one attached:

`=COUNTIFS(DATE_C3,"<="&DATE_C3,DATE_D5_COMP,">="&DATE_C3")`

[image]

Comment: Try countifs(), ie if the date is greater or equal to created and less or equal to closed, but you may want less than closed only depending how  you see it...

Answer (score 0):

Create your desired months Jan|Feb...as dates
Then, you can use date math to get it.

For example, here, I put your input data in A1:C4 
The formulas for each month of output are like:

```
=COUNTIFS($B2:$B4,"<="&F1,$C2:$C4,">="&F1)
```

[image]